# Unable to initiate application class from dynamic module

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

In base app, have the `Application` class and declared into `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
public class App : SplitCompatApplication() {

     override fun onCreate() {
       super.onCreate()
     }
}

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

In dynamic module, which should be downloaded onDemand, have another `Application` class.

```
public class OnDemandApplication : Application() {

     override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
         super.attachBaseContext(base)
         SplitCompat.install(this)
     }

     override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        /* compiled code */
     }
}
```

How can I initiate the dynamic module application class?

Comment: How do you expect that to work? An app has a single Application class. You can't have multiple

Comment: yes, but some function need to initialize from application class in dynamic module. how can I do that?